# Edit XML file using JDOM

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, jdom

I want to add `xmlns:atom` to the root element of an XML file, the file already exists, I just want to modify it by adding the adding `xmlns`. The rest of the files is to be left unchanged. As an example, I have `<rss version="2.0">` in file and I want to convert it in to `<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">` using JDOM. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the input file loaded as a JDOM Document, you can:

```
document.getRootElement().addNamespaceDeclaration(
    Namespace.getNamespace("atom", "..."));
```

Then, when you output the document it will have the additional namespace declaration.

Make sure you use the right URI for your Namespace... not '...' ...

See the documentation for [addNamespaceDeclaration](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html#addNamespaceDeclaration%28org.jdom2.Namespace%29):